# some lost details in the proof of Rouché's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ and $g$ be analytic on an open region $S$. Let $\gamma$ be a Jordan circuit with graph $\Gamma$
> such that both $\Gamma$ and its inner region lie within $S$. Suppose that $|g(z)| < |f(z)|$ for every
> $z$ on $\Gamma$
>
> (a) Show that
> $$
> \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f'(z) + g'(z)}{f(z) + g(z)} \, dz = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} \, dz.
> $$
> *Hint.* Let $m = \inf \{ |f(z) - g(z)| : z \in \Gamma \}$. Then $m > 0$ and hence
> $$
> |f(z) + g(z)| \geq m > 0
> $$
> for each $t$ in $[0, 1]$ and each $z$ on $\Gamma$. Now let
> $$
> \Phi(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f'(z) + tg'(z)}{f(z) + tg(z)} \, dz, \quad \text{if } 0 \leq t \leq 1.
> $$
> Then $\Phi$ is continuous, and hence constant, on $[0, 1]$. Thus, $\Phi(0) = \Phi(1)$.
> (b) Use (a) to prove that $f$ and $f + g$ have the same number of zeros inside $\Gamma$
> (Rouch'e's theorem).

My confusions:I cannot understand why that $\Phi(t)$ is continuous implies  $\Phi(t)$ constant.

I tried to to calculate the differentiation of $\Phi(t)$.But $\Phi'(t) = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{g'(z)f(z) - f'(z)g(z)}{(f(z) + tg(z))^2} z’$where $z=\gamma(\theta)$.It is not zero?

for part [b] by using argument principle,I need to prove the number of poles of $f$ and $f+g$ inside $\Gamma$ is the same.But why?
The problem is the exercrise 16.14 in Mathematical analysis(apostol).
And the solution on the quizlet is https://quizlet.com/explanations/textbook-solutions/mathematical-analysis-2nd-edition-9780201002881/chapter-16-exercises-14-18305922-00c9-45f0-be56-6292c25fb453

Comment: It is integer valued and continuous, hence a constant. $f$ and $g$ are analytic, so there are no poles.

Comment: Concise and to-the-point answer！

Answer (score 0):

For (a), you crucially need the following property: For a general meromorphic function $f: S \longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ and any closed curve $\gamma : [a,b]\longrightarrow S$, it holds that

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_\gamma \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz = N(f)-P(f),$$
where $N(f)$ is the number of zeros of $f$ in the area encircled by $\gamma$, while $P(f)$ is the number of poles in the same area. There difference thus is a number in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Then if $f,g$ are both meromorphic, so is $f(z)+tg(z)$ for all $t\in [0,1]$. Thus, one gets that
$$\Phi(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_\gamma \frac{f'(z) + tg'(z)}{f(z) + tg(z)} dz = N(f+tg)-P(f+tg),$$

i.e. $\Phi:[0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ is a continuous function (note that the denominator can never vanish due to $|g(z)|<|f(z)|$ along $\gamma$) into a discrete space and thus has to be constant, so for $t=0$ and $t=1$ it follows that

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_\gamma \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} dz = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_\gamma \frac{f'(z) + g'(z)}{f(z) + g(z)} dz$$

For (b), we use that $f$ and $g$ are actually holomorphic, i.e. $P(f)=P(g)=0$ and thus (a) means that
$$N(f) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_\gamma \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} dz=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_\gamma \frac{f'(z)+g'(z)}{f(z)+g(z)}dz = N(f+g).$$

Comment: I missed the key point that $\Phi(t)$is a integer and it's continious. Thus it's a constant.Thank you very much for your answer!